# Match single character in .net regex

Tags: c#, regex

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx), the `.` character

> Matches any single character except \n.

In this case, why does this regex not match?:

```
Regex.IsMatch("c",@"[.]")
```

Comment: http://regexpal.com/  This site is helpful for regex experimentation.

Comment: Cheers. I normally use that. It appears i wasnt aware you couldnt use the wild card character inside a character group. One of those things im amazed ive got this far without discovering!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are matching `[.]` which means character `.`. Use just `.` to get your result. The `[]` mean any of the character inside. So by `.` loses its special meaning because of this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/19

`c` is being captured by the second group, not the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `.` inside `[]` to get all characters. Remove the `[]` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `@"[.]";` with `@".";` // Use `.`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("c", @"."));
```

If you do this often, then add

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Match(this string value, String query)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(value, query);
    }

    public static void Out<t>(this t value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

After that you can use

```
"c".Match(".").Out();
```

Comment: Very true (and in fact I already have all sorts of extension methods for string operations). Im aware the code could be more concise, its intentionally verbose as i wanted to make sure i wasnt missing anything until id worked this out.